# RxJs zip operator, check which one throws an error and continue on condition?

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I've 2 api service calls that I zip into one observable:

```
const firstAPIrequest = this.firstApi.getData();
const secondAPIrequest = this.secondApi.getData();

const combined = zip(firstAPIrequest, secondAPIrequest);
```

I currently map these to return an array:

```
combined.pipe(
   map((res) => {
      return [res[0], res[1]) // just an example
   }
);
```

Then I use it as a subscription in a different component

```
combined.subscribe(
   (res) => this.handleData(res),
   (err) => {
      console.debug('Fetch failed', err);
   }
)
```

In this case, if one of the API request failed it will show an error, but I would like to check in between which one failed, for example; if `request1` returned data and `request2` failed I would still return the data from `request1`

I've tried `catchError` but I don't think I can get the data in this function

```
combined.pipe(
   catchError((err) => ...), // how would I catch the data before it throws an error?
   map((res) => {
      return [res[0], res[1]) // just an example
   }
);
```

Comment: Do you wish to handle the errors or completely ignore them?

Comment: @MichaelD not ignore them completely, rather if both fail throw error, if only one fails and the other one works it should not throw

Answer (score 3):

To handle errors from each source individually, the `catchError` must be piped into each of them individually. `catchError` must return an observable, so we'll use RxJS `of` function for it.

```js
import { of, catchError } from 'rxjs';

const handleError = (error: any) => of({error: error});

const firstAPIrequest = this.firstApi.getData().pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
const secondAPIrequest = this.secondApi.getData().pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);

const combined = zip(firstAPIrequest, secondAPIrequest);
```

Now in the subscription you could check if the response is valid or an error.

```js
combined.subscribe(
  ([res1, res2]) => {
    if (!!res1.error && !!res2.error) {
      // both API calls threw error
    } else if (!!res1.error) {
      // `firstAPIrequest` threw error
    } else if (!!res2.error) {
      // `secondAPIrequest` threw error
    } else {
      // both returned responses
    }
  }
);
```

Note: this assumes the actual response doesn't contain a property `error`. If so replace the `error` property in the `handleError` function with something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but It still throws the error in subscribe(), the error gets attached to the object but I can't get subscription to ignore the default error

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is the exact expected behavior? With the current implementation the `error` callback of the subscription would never be triggered since the errors are transformed to `next` emissions using the `of` function.

Answer (score 1):

you have to catch error on both of the sources, because if you caught the error after combining, the combination stream stops after the first error. for example:

```
const replaceErrorWithNull = catchError(() => of(null));

const firstAPIrequest = this.firstApi.getData();
const secondAPIrequest = this.secondApi.getData();

const combined = zip(
  firstAPIrequest.pipe(replaceErrorWithNull), 
  secondAPIrequest.pipe(replaceErrorWithNull)
);
```

with this approach null will be in place of data from API that errored

Comment: Thanks, so I can't just check if only one of them fails?

Comment: if I got the question right, then with this code, if the 1st API failed and the 2nd is ok, you will get te result as `[null, {...data}]`